# logic for slider dynamic images loop with php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, carousel

I am working on bootstrap carousel slider. I am trying to load the dynamic images in the slider with PHP array. I have 4(count is not fixed) image paths in PHP array.

My HTML code below:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar1.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar2.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar1.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar2.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar1.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar2.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a logic to loop the array and load my images in the html.

My expected HTML like

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar1.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar2.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar3.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar1.jpg" alt=""></a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

please help me

Comment: whats current output ?

Comment: loading all images in first item active div only. but i need to load divided by 3

Comment: check the answer i've added below

Answer (score 2):

do like this

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <?php
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($images as $key => $image)
        {
            if ($count == 2)
            {
            ?>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                <?php
                $count = 0;
            }
            ?>
                <a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/<?= $image?>" alt=""></a>
            <?php
            $count += 1;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**What you should do in above code**

1. `$images` should be your array name
2. `<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/<?= $image?>` add the correct path here

---

**What happens in above code**

Each and every time `<a>` tab with print inside `<img>` and whenever it meets `if == 2` (count is 3) it will add new `<div>` and make count to 0

Comment: it's working like a charm, Thanks a lot. Small change is if ($count == 2) to if ($count == 3) then its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

$count = 1;

```
 foreach( $images as $img ) 
 {
   if ($count%4 == 1)
  {  
     echo '<div class="item active">';

  }
  echo '<a href=""><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/product-details/similar1.jpg" alt=""></a>';

  if ($count%4 == 0)
  {
          echo "</div>";
  }
   $count++;
 }
  if ($count%4 != 1) echo "</div>";
```